# python search only int on a list that has int and str

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a poker app on pyton.
The problem I am dealing with currently is this.
First of all I need to tell you that I have 4 arrays.

1. NUMBERS = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
2. COLORS = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
3. DECK (which comes from appending NUMBERS and COLORS so it has ["Spades", 2], ["Spades", 3]) etc.)
4. PLCARDS1 (which contains 1 card from. DECK for example ["Spades", "A"])
5. PLCARDS2 (which also contains 1 card from DECK)
6. PLCARDS (which contains PLCARDS1 and PLCARDS2 )
7. RIVER (which contains 5 cards from DECK)

So everything is right. I mean each card is different for everyone and you can play a round (without coming to a winner ).
I need to compare the PLCARDS to RIVER so I can find for example if the player has a pair ("A" and "A").
My problem is that I need to compare ONLY the second part of the array. 
I tried this

```
   if PLCARDS1 == NUMBERS:  
        if NUMBERS == RIVER:  
            pair += pair
```

This does not work because it searches for ["Spades", 7] in NUMBERS = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

Is there in function or something that isolates the right/left part of an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splicing](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/).
In your case you can get only ints by

```
NUMBERS[:9]
```

and only strings by

```
NUMBERS[9:]
```

Besides, I think your problem is not just about splicing, but you need to better comprehend python as language. I suppose it is an exercise, isn't?
For example if you need to handle cards I give you 2 suggestions:

1. use str for every element in NUMBERS:

   NUMBERS = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

because you don't need to threat them as int

2. in your deck and hands, to identify a card use a tuple:
   DECK = [("Spades", "2"),("Spades", "3"), etcetera]

In both arrays and tuples you can use the [] notation to access the elements, so if you need to check for the color of the *i* card in your hand you can do like this:

```
if PLCARDS[i][0] == "Spades":
```

For a better comprehension, have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Comment: Thank you.  I know about my conditions but I wrote that in a hurry.  So my problem with this you mention is that "A", "K", "Q" and "J" are not int. Should I use splicing in PLCARDS? Because PLCARDS is the list I need to isolate. If it has (["Spades", 2], ["Spades", 3]) I need to isolate 2 and 3 and search on NUMBERS list

Comment: I understood you needed to splice NUMBERS. Maybe it is better if you edit your question in order to explain better what do you need to accomplish.

Comment: hmm let me make it more clear first. If I print PLCARDS i will get as a result [0, [10,'Spades']], [0,['A', 'Hearts']]. So I don't need only the integers. I need the part 10 or 'A' of my array